# Mysql Select a set of records and Update them

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if there is any way of updating a set of records just after selecting them in a query. I mean I need to get a set of records and depending on the set fetched, update the 'read' field to 1.

Can i do it in an only query or I need to do it separately?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe that you can do it in one query - you'll need to SELECT the data, and then perform an UPDATE.

Comment: How about a cursor in procedure?

Comment: You are looking to both fetch the data for other purposes AND update the `read` field, correct?

Comment: YES DJ QUIMBY, thats the idea... I need to show that set of records in screen and update the read field when shown.

Comment: In this case I believe @andrewsi is correct, you will need to do this with two statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example: change the table names, criteria in where clause according to your need.

```
update abc 
set read = 1
where a in (select p from pqr where p=q)
```

based on your latest comment to your question, you would need 2 queries:

```
  $rs = mysql_query("select p from pqr where p=q");
```

Put the 2nd query inside a loop, traversing the resultset of 1st query

```
 foreach( $rs as $v)  
 mysql_query("update abc set read = 1 where a = $v");
```

Comment: This would result in more queries to the database than is ultimately necessary.  I would recommend that the same where clause be used to update the records.

Comment: well, it depends on which table, and what criteria the OP needs in the queries.

Answer (score 0):

You do **not** have to **select them at all**. If you know what your `WHERE` will be for selecting, the same WHERE can be used for updating.

Suppose you would select your records with:

```
select foo, bar from foobar where foo like '%fo'
```

then you would update the records like this

```
update foobar set bar='new' where foo like '%fo'
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to use just a single query? If it's consistency, try using a DB with transactions, or at the very least lock the table before issuing the two queries. But ultimately, two queries is fine - it should be the same time complexity as a single query. Don't fear the double query! :D